App Store Connect Issue: Rejected Subscriptions Despite Proper Setup
I’m running into an issue with App Store Connect and was hoping someone here might have some insights.
I have a simple app with one subscription model (monthly) that I’ve added in App Store Connect. However, my app keeps getting rejected for two reasons:
Rejection #1:

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness


We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

They’ve asked me to resubmit the in-app purchases and upload a new binary, but I’ve already added the subscription in the app.
Rejection #2:

Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase


We have begun the review of your in-app purchases but aren't able to continue because your submitted in-app purchases indicate a change of business model for your app. Therefore, we need to verify the implementation of your submitted in-app purchases.

I’m using RevenueCat for handling the subscription model, and I’ve added in-app purchases in the Signing & Capabilities section in Xcode.
The problem:
I only have a monthly subscription model implemented in the app.
When I tried adding in-app purchases, the options are only consumable or non-consumable. The auto-renewable subscription type isn’t showing up for me, so I didn’t add any in-app purchases, since I thought the subscription setup should cover it.
I submitted the app for review, but it keeps getting rejected with the same reasons.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or know how to solve this? I'm not sure what I might be missing here.










You don't need an in app purchase if you are using a subscription. The screenshots show that your subscription was rejected  probably because your description does not meet Apple's requirements. Check for the message they gave you when the subscription was rejected. They also say they are going to call you to try and help
